# Update MySQL table from an MSSQL Table with Talend

Tags: mysql, sql-server, talend

I want to update a MySQL table with values retrieved from an MSSQL table in Talend.

I used the MSSQL table as a tMSSqlUnput, a tMap and the MySQL table as a tMysqlOutput but I couldn't update establish a join query and update the table.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define key in schema of tMysqlOutput and also select action as Update. THis way talend would generate update statement by using key columns in the update where clause...and process them at mysql DB.

It will be done for each row coming out of tMap.

if you want to write your own sql then you should use tMysqlRow..

Comment: the problem is that I want to match (join) the tables. I can give you an SQL query to more explain the issue:
UPDATE A SET field2 = (SELECT B.field2 WHERE A.field1 = B.field2);
(A and B are two tables that does not belong to the same base neither to the same server)

Comment: ok in that case you should first bring/dump data to be processed from A table into stage_A table in the database where B resides. Then use tmysqlRow to execute your sql using stage_A and B. this would be much faster instead of row by row processing.

Comment: That's what I did ;) Thank you :)

Comment: Actually, I found another solution that could be better :

* I retrieved the data from the MSSQL table (table A)

* I used a tMap with an output named "test" and where I mapped the fileds needed

* Then, I used the output variables (test.field1, test.field2...) in an update query that I put in a tMysqlRow

I hope that it will be useful for others ;)

Comment: yes that will work too, but it will run update for each row but that might be slower if you have to process huge volume of data when compared to dump table and fire update once for all rows.